# qemu gpu passthrough black screen

Tags: graphics, kvm-virtualization

previously at may 2017 I have configured a virtual qemu machine with a gpu passthrought of a radeon 5450, it works fine except a kernel panic (on VM) after the 2nd boot of the VM...

Now I am trying to remake this machine with the same configuration ( just 1-2 things different)
formerly :

- Gigabyte GA-990-FXA-ud3
- AMD FX6300
- 1st graphic card : NVidia GT210
- 2nd graphic card : AMD Radeon HD5450
- debian 8

changes since :

- AMD FX8350
- 1st graphic card : NVidia GT710

(I know its a little bit outdated configuration but I am not a gamer so I do not need more)

I have written this startup script :

```
#/bin/sh

echo '0000:02:00.1' | tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.1/driver/unbind

modprobe vfio
modprobe vfio_pci

echo 1002 68f9 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
echo 1002 aa68 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id


qemu-system-x86_64 -M q35 -m 2048 -enable-kvm \
-bios OVMF.fd \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-soundhw ac97 \
-hda virtualrawdrive -cdrom ubuntuinstall.iso \
-device piix4-ide,bus=pcie.0,id=piix4-ide  -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1,bus=pcie.0 \
-vnc :0
```

but Its not working, when I launch the script, 2nd graphic card VGA screen lights up, displays ubuntu plymouth screen, and after nothing, the screen stays on, but displays a black screen.

My lspci -nnk :

```
[...]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] [10de:128b] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK208B [GeForce GT 710] [1458:36f7]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [10de:0e0f] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1458:36f7]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] [1002:68f9]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] [1462:2127]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: radeon
02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series] [1002:aa68]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series] [1462:aa68]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
[...]
```

My former 2017 script :

```
echo '0000:02:00.1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.1/driver/unbind

modprobe vfio
modprobe vfio_pci

echo 1002 68f9 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
echo 1002 aa68 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 2048 -cpu host -smp 2,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=1 \
-bios /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin \
-vga none -device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device piix4-ide,bus=pcie.0,id=piix4-ide  -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1,bus=pcie.0 \
-soundhw ac97 \
-drive file=/home/user/ubuntuimage,id=disk,format=raw,if=none -device ide-hd,bus=piix4-ide.0,drive=disk
```

I think the problem comes from the "x-vga=on" option, but it not works on the new versions, I have got this error :

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: vfio 0000:02:00.0: failed getting region info for VGA region index 8: Invalid argument
device does not support requested feature x-vga
```

I have try use a "fresh" version of qemu (4.0.0) and OVMF (compiled from the GIT sources) but It does not changes anything...

So thanks by advance for your aswers

PS : sorry for my bad english, I am french

Comment: A general approach to issues like this that I use is setting up the guest without GPU passthrough and make it booting into an SSH-login ready state. That way after later adding the GPU even if all output is failing you can log in to debug the logs of the guest e.g. does it see the card, does X initialize, ...; once you have done so taking a look at the dmesg of guest and host also often is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to last comment, I have installed the OS in emulated graphic card, then I reboot from gpu passtrought and everything works perfectly !

My start script :

```
#!/bin/sh

#network configuration
/usr/bin/tunctl -t tap0
/sbin/brctl addif br0 tap0
/sbin/ifconfig tap0 up

#passtrought configuration
echo '0000:02:00.1' | tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.1/driver/unbind

modprobe vfio
modprobe vfio_pci

echo 1002 68f9 | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
echo 1002 aa68 | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

#virtual machine start
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -M q35 -m 6144 -enable-kvm -smp 2 \
-bios /path/to/OVMF.fd \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 -vga none \
-usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x0461,productid=0x4d20 -device usb-host,vendorid=0x0b38,productid=0x0003 -soundhw ac97 \
-drive file=OS-image.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw \
-vnc :0 \
-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
-device piix4-ide,bus=pcie.0,id=piix4-ide  -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1,bus=pcie.0 \


exit 0
```